# build a regex for password check

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Hi i have a password strength check in PHP. that looks like this:

```
    public static function validPass($candidate) {
    $r1 = '/[A-Z]/';  //1 upper
    $r2 = '/[a-z]/';  //2 lower
    $r3 = '/[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{}:<.>]/';  //1 special char
    $r4 = '/[0-9]/';  //1 number

    //no space
    if (preg_match('/\s/',$candidate)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (preg_match_all($r1, $candidate, $o) < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (preg_match_all($r2, $candidate, $o) < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (preg_match_all($r3, $candidate, $o) < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (preg_match_all($r4, $candidate, $o) < 1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

so 1 capital, 1 lower, 1 number, 1 special char and no spaces allowed

now i am using a javascript validator for the frontend and the only custom feature i can add for password is to add a regex so i have to build this into a regex. I tried and I have so far:

```
^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])$
```

but  i dont know how to approach this. What is the best way to perform these checks into a regex?

Comment: Oh god everybody hates this. "Your password must be at least 24 characters long, contain at least 1 number, 1 capital letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 special character, 1 Mayan symbol and 1 Egyptian hyeroglyph, must not in any way look like your previous password, and will expire in one week." *_Leaves the site_*

Comment: I do not agree with this Aa@1 would resolve to a valid pass... in this time and era its important to train users to use strong passwords. altough you hate it. if every website requires this, it will be the standard

Comment: Try one-click Google or Facebook login buttons. Impossible passwords that you have to write on a post-it are a big no-no for users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])$` pattern is an example of a regex that will never match because, with lookaheads, you require at least 1 non-letter, uppercase and lowercase letters, but the consuming pattern only matches an empty string.

You may use a single regex like

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_=+{}:<.>-])(?=.*[0-9])\S*$
```

If you need to set a minmum number of characters, replace the last `*` with a limiting quantifier, e.g. `{8,}` to require at least 8 chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHNwiB/1).

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - at least one uppercase
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - - at least one lowercase
- `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_=+{}:<.>-])` - at least one special char
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - at least one digit
- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of strings.