# How to write a regex matching word_char but only zero or one underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a username to test:

1. it is made up of at least 4 characters
2. it can contain only word character, number, and underscore (max. one time)
3. it should start with a word character and it cannot end with an underscore.

I have written this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z][^\W_]{2,}_?[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

But I really have no idea how to limit the appearance of underscore (0-1 times).

How can I achieve my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookahead to check the more-specific qualifications, then apply the general rule of `\w{4,}`.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0aZVAn/1)

```js
const tests = ['_und', 'u_nd', 'un_d', 'und_', 'u_n_', 'u__d', '8_no'];
for (i in tests) {
    document.write(tests[i] + ' => ' + /^(?=[a-z][^_]*_?[^_]+$)\w{4,}$/i.test(tests[i]) + "<br>");
}
```

```
(?=         #lookahead
  [a-z]     #a letter
  [^_]*     #zero or more non-underscores
  _?        #an optional underscore
  [^_]+$    #one or more non-underscores until the end of the string
)
```

---

It can also be done without a lookahead but the length check of 4 or more characters becomes implicit instead of explicit.  In other words, humans who read the pattern will need to determine the the minimum length of the string is 4 by understanding conditional expressions and summing the implemented quantifiers.

```js
const tests = [
  'und',
  '_und',
  'u_nd',
  'un_d',
  'und_',
  'u_n_',
  'u__d',
  '8_no',
  'u_derscore',
  'un_erscore',
  'und_rscore',
  'unde_score',
  'under_co_e',
  'underscor_',
  '_nderscore'
];
for (i in tests) {
    document.write(tests[i] + ' => ' + /^[a-z](?:_[^\W_]{2,}|[^\W_]_[^\W_]+|[^\W_]{2,}_?[^\W_]+)$/i.test(tests[i]) + "<br>");
}
```

Breakdown:

```
/                        #pattern delimiter
^                        #start of string anchor
[a-z]                    #alphabetical character
(?:                      #non-capturing group
  _[^\W_]{2,}            #underscore, two or more alnum characters (at least 3 characters)
  |                      #or
  [^\W_]_[^\W_]+         #alnum character, underscore, one or more non-underscore (at least 3 characters)
  |                      #or
  [^\W_]{2,}_?[^\W_]+    #two or more alnum characters, optional underscore, one or more alnum characters (at least 3 characters)
)                        #end of non-capturing group
$                        #end of string anchor
/                        #pattern delimiter
i                        #case-insensitive pattern modifier
```

Comment: You save my life.HAHAHa, thanks a lot. I even don't know the usage of lookahead. Btw, is it possible to solve it without using lookahead?

Comment: but I think, maybe better use [^\W_] stands for non-underscores better than [^_]? Cuz it may be accepted if the symbol is ., \, etc..

Comment: The lookahead allows the regex engine to enforce rules before actually consuming/matching characters, then after the lookahead is satisfied, the engine will continue traversing the string.  I updates my answer to include a pattern without a lookahead, but it is longer and I find it harder to read.  The reason I used `[^_]` in the first snippet was because the `\w{4,}` was enforcing the whole string character range.

Comment: Using lookaheads to enforce password strength rules is very common. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43697894/2943403